# HTML in Django db

Tags: django

I have a model:

```
class Pages(models.Model):
    meta_d = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    meta_k = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    text = models.TextField()
```

But if in db I have, for example, `<h1>123</h1>` in "text" column, it return in html-file this like a string, not **123** (h1). So, in admin interface I can write an article with html-tags. And I can see that tags in my site like a strings. Its wrong.

Comment: you need to use `{{obj.text|safe}}` the `safe` filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use what @karthikr put in his comment:

```
{{data|safe}}
```

or if you need to work it against block of template (not only one variable as above), use as follows:

```
{% autoescape off %}
{{ data }}
{{ data2 }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

DJango displays html tags in strings as they are to protect from a Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attack.
You can find the complete description in the official DJango documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping